# How to auto feed-in the data to the webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to ask if somebody has the idea on how to auto feed in the data to your webpage. What I mean is, if I'm uploading data to my website I want to automatically display it to the other page which is displayed in a separate tab because I have a photo gallery page and I  want to see my uploaded files in that page without hitting the refresh button of the browser. All I've got right now is the auto-refresh codes but that doesn't apply it to this scenario. Other example is the news feed of your facebook. If your friend is posting something then it automatically be displayed to your news feed page, that is what I'm trying to get...I hope somebody can get my point. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the "cool" stuff for realtime web in. Net: http://signalr.net/

Answer (score 1):

You can make an AJAX call every, let's say, 5 seconds.

If you are using Jquery in your site, you can try:

```
var seconds = 5;

setInterval(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: urlToHandler,
        data: jsonData,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(data) {
           $('#container').html(data.html)
        },
        error: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
            console.log('There was an error.');
        }
    });      // end $.ajax
}, seconds * 1000)
```

Comment: I think this is just like the auto-refresh codes.The functionality is like auto-refresh which sets time to refresh, that doesn't apply to this scenario because I don't want to refresh the page every certain period of time. Somebody told me about SignalR which makes sense to me but I don't know how to use it. Any idea

Comment: No, this is not auto-refresh!! This sends a request to the server every 5 seconds. The server checks if you posted new items and responses back with the html of your feed container which will eventually change. This is how most 'live' feeds work, including FB, SO, etc.

Comment: The html of your feed container will change without causing any postback or refresh, because it happens on client.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this..in order for me to use that code What class I need to add in my website project both Ajax and JQuery?

Comment: @timmack add only `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>` to your .aspx page, and you can make it even by only using plain javascript. but you have to read something more than just my answer on how to make ajax requests to server.

Comment: This is the "old school" method of using AJAX to poll the server for any new information. It works and it works well. I've implemented it many times myself. **_BUT_** This is basically a workaround for an inherit shortcoming of the web world. The answer from @Xelom uses the "next-generation" of web technologies: websockets. This is true real-time communication between the client and the server. I would go that route for any new development.

Comment: It maybe the next generation, but it's not widely supported yet, is it?